# How do I put photos on an SD card to view in a camera?

Tags: camera, memory-card

I have some images on my computer that I put on an SD card to view in a camera. I made sure they were all jpegs, and transferred them to the SD card, but they don't show up in the preview in the LCD of the camera.

Is there a way to do this? Do I need a program that can appropriately add the photos to the SD card, or can I do it manually?

---

I did put them in the DCIM folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have to put them in a DCIM folder on the root of the SD card. If that doesn't work, take a picture (any will do), open it up on the computer, then paste the pictures in the folder created by the camera.

One more thing. Some cameras will refuse to show images with different aspect ratios or resolutions than the camera itself takes, in order to reduce the size of the firmware, presumably allowing smaller chips, meaning smaller cameras (also cheaper).

Comment: Are you saying overwrite one of the camera's existing images with the image I want? Genius! Is there any concern about format compatability? Like color depth, quality?

Comment: Probably not, just basically same image format (i.e. JPEG, BMP, GIF, though I highly doubt that it won't be JPEG (.jpg)).

Comment: You don't need to overwrite an image, you just need to find out how the camera stores images and put them in with the same naming.  The picture with the camera is simply to find the rules it uses.